# I have made a java frame in netbeans 8.1 ,i want to give a button on it which mails the its data to entered email id . How to do?

Tags: java

I have designed a java application  in netbeans 8.1 and i want to give a button on the frame which mails the information  on frame to entered email id . How can I do that?'

Comment: It is too broad question,google how to send email in java

Comment: Please add what you have tried, where you are stuck or anything that is question-related. You must first lookup before asking such a broad question